# Typescript assuming I am returning any string even when explicitly checking if the return value is included in an array of specific strings

Tags: typescript

Consider this code:

```
const shorcutOptions = ['val1', 'val2'];

type ValueType = number | string;
type ReturnType = number | 'val1' | 'val2';

export function validValue(value: ValueType): ReturnType {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    /**
     * If it's a string, check if it is one of the shortcuts.
     * If so, return it as is.
     */
    if (shorcutOptions.includes(value)) return value; // issue here

    /**
     * Anything below is just for the sake of making this example
     * and is of no consequence.
     */
    return parseInt(value);
  }

  if (typeof value === 'number') return value;

  return 500;
}
```

My problem is that on the line marked with `// issue here`, where I'm getting the red squiggly line under `return value;` with this error in typescript:

> `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.ts(2322)`

I don't understand why it would assume it's just any `string` because I'm explicitly checking if `value` is included in the `shortcutOptions` array, which means it will only return `value` if it is equal to `'val1'` or `'val2'`.

I can replace the if statement with `if (value === 'val1' || value === 'val2')` but in my real-world use-case, I have many more options and it seems redundant.

I can also replace `string` in `type ValueType = ...` with `'val1' | 'val2`, and the error goes away, but I need this function to accept any string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why the compiler doesn't do the analysis you are expecting.  One is that the compiler infers that the type of `shortCutoptions` to be `string[]` and not an array containing [literal string types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) like `'val1'` and `'val2'`.  Such inference is often what is intended, but in your case you want the compiler to keep track of the specific values in the array and presumably not let people modify its contents.  You can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask for a narrower inferred type:

```
const shorcutOptions = ['val1', 'val2'] as const;
// const shorcutOptions: readonly ["val1", "val2"]
```

The compiler infers a readonly tuple of string literals.

---

The next problem is that the [TS standard library's typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.9.5/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts#L27) for [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) does not act as a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  So checking `arr.includes(val)` does not serve to narrow the type of `val`.  This is as intended, and suggestions to change this have been declined (see [microsoft/TypeScript#36275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275) for instance).

But, if you want the compiler to act this way for arrays of string literals, you can make your own type guard function that uses `includes()` in its implementation... for example:

```
function includesString<T extends string>(arr: readonly T[], val: string): val is T {
  return (arr as readonly string[]).includes(val);
}
```

Now if you use that, the compiler will assume that a `true` result implies that `val` has been narrowed from `string`:

```
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (includesString(shorcutOptions, value)) return value; // okay
    return parseInt(value);
  }
```

Looks good to me.  If you only want to do this once, you could also just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in the `return` statement:

```
if ((shorcutOptions as readonly string[]).includes(value))
  return value as typeof shorcutOptions[number];
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAhgCwgJzAVzgeQA5wCW0MCAvAgNoDkAbgIYA2AjNQDQJ1MBM1AugnqlIsOAG5QAekkIR8JKgzZ8REgC4EaAKb0AJtEYBPKgCIGLExzM8TfUKDiG8WhADUmmLQBUnLilEwAWwAjLTQEAB8kODRCKABzCRBHZwQAJS04TDQoH1T-INDwqK4WakjOc14k0AAzTCgwVSgEOLBGTF0tGABlGLj4gB4vBC0ADzgtKF1SeFiEgD4ACno0NA1tPQNjL0o+DnMNOYGASg1zVtIRgG9QBE1M7JaVtcFSTf0oI2j5+L2TgB0bQ6XRgS3MJySAF97CBxnh0Ih6o1mghzIRdO4OlpwR4tBosZ48lozulHjliQhbiB7oRaggliktBB6eZPOQyBRqMcEtQTlS7vdWvSlsDOt0+r8lih0FhcARiLADniTvztFkcmi8WIENIEBAANb0QyC+7qp4IPCrGBaACSUDguOxkMFMJAgrpDKZLK12I5XICITCfIeGpabK0SQQgvNmoArAAGBPQ2HwxEIZFNRW+jGErTcJ2eAl44mkjJhynUj0i72svH+zg8+Ih6lC4UM6WKOUqRWkIQPLZfYxN-5Axog7qFkknU1C2Ph+v92sKWXKBUkSiBop8KNz8ktK1oG32x0Rl00hBu6te3w+iMN6hb4Nq-e+zw1C-zhCJ5OgK-ugCpD1AAZW0ACEEAAUR6bgE2YAA2XVpFALp2lWFx4kYCBgiYAULziSY0FqegwBcDJByMABBNZjWGBY8LbMVQWlHQMGQSDGC0QIpjgDQvA4Wo0AgQJ7S6MYAH4NCfNBSWCCAIE4+goF3N03SAA)

Comment: Thanks, `includesString` did the trick. I added it to my utils as I expect to do this more than once.