# Typescript array subset based on object keys not allowed

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have object properties being looped through generically, some of the number props needed additional calculations, and I ended up with this (simplified) situation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated: I get an "unassignable" compile error on both lines in the main function.

```
interface Data {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}
const data = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}

const ar: (keyof Data)[] = ["a", "b", "c"]

type Allowed = Omit<Data, "c">
var allowedAr: (keyof Allowed)[] = [ "a", "b" ]


function main(key: keyof Data) {
  if (allowedAr.includes(key))
    allowedFn(key)
}

function allowedFn(key: keyof Allowed) {}
```

Comment: Your question is quite similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482699/how-can-i-use-array-includes-in-typescript-between-different-types/67483028#67483028).

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747808/typescript-assuming-i-am-returning-any-string-even-when-explicitly-checking-if-t); you will probably want to use a user-defined type guard function like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wXRB1m) shows.

Comment: These are perfect thank you!  I didn't realize Arary.includes didn't work as a type guard, and that I could define my own-- the code is really helpful for understanding it too, thanks